# Deferring mortgage interest expense to next year when filing taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, mortgage, interest

I paid around $25,000 in mortgage interest payment last year, however, I had no income. I was wondering if I could defer this expense to next year and omit it this year. Since it will not benefit me to include this in my itemized tax file.

Answer (score 11):

No. That's not an option. 
Unfortunately, it's a bit late to strategize, but in 2014, I'd have suggested that you take IRA money and convert it to Roth. Of course this only works if you have a pretax IRA or 401(k) you can convert. Between your exemption ($3900) and this deduction, you could have converted $30K with no tax due. More, taking property tax and any other itemized deductions into account.